# Throughput issue in Cassandra client communication

Tags: cassandra, datastax, rhel, cassandra-3.0

I've got a single node Cassandra cluster(3.11.2)(RHEL 6.5). I'm observing huge differences in the throughput when my client is on the same node on which my database resides vs when my client is on some other computer. The difference is more than 4x! I don't think this is normal.

I had [read](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/faq/index.html#what-ports) that port 9042 is used for client communications in Cassandra. If the same port is being used in both scenarios, is the latency being observed in the 2nd scenario due to slow connectivity between the 2 nodes?

For the 2nd scenario, I used the following command on the client side:

```
time nc -zw30 172.16.129.140 9042 //(172.16.129.140 is the IP_addr_of_database_node)
Connection to 172.16.129.140 9042 port [tcp/*] succeeded!

real    0m0.007s
user    0m0.005s
sys     0m0.001s
```

Are these values too high? What other linux commands can be useful to get a quantitative measure of the latency in client communication in both scenarios?

I'm using Datastax C++ driver for client.

Comment: are you blocking on synchronous requests or using async api?

Comment: I'm doing async queries(using callbacks) in both scenarios.

Comment: I'm thinking latency might have something to do with it. Have you tried increasing concurrent_writes and concurrent_writes to allow more queries to be handled at the same time? Also increasing the heap might help.